# Posicionamiento de texto

Tags: html, css

Necesito posicionar texto alrededor de una imagen. ejemplo
[image: texto alrededor]

Así es como posicioné cada texto, pero me da problemas para que sea responsive. Por el momento se ve bien en mi pantalla pero al revisarlo en una mas grande se descuadra. ¿Alguna idea de cómo hacerlo correctamente?

```
.benefits1 {
    margin-top: -95%;
    width: 26%;
    margin-left: 13%;
    @include breakpoint(desktop) {
        margin-top: -452px;
        width: 26%;
        margin-left: 8%;
    }
}

.benefits2 {
    margin-left: 80%;
    margin-top: -10%;
    width: 22%;
    @include breakpoint(desktop) {
        margin-left: 60%;
        margin-top: 42px;
        width: 24%;
    }
}

.benefits3 {
    margin-top: 69%;
    margin-left: 60%;
    width: 40%;
    @include breakpoint(desktop) {
        margin-top: 219px;
    margin-left: 44%;
    width: 2%;
    }
}

.benefits4 {
    margin-top: -37%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    width: 21%;
    @include breakpoint(desktop) {
        margin-top: -139px;
        margin-left: -4%;
        width: 2%;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="list-benefits">
        <img src="assets/images/beneficios.png" alt="Beneficios">
        <p class="benefits1">CONTROL FUNCIONES CRÍTICAS</p>
        <p class="benefits2">VISIBILIDAD RECURSOS DEL PERSONAL</p>
        <p class="benefits3">CONTROL PRESUPUESTARIO</p>
        <p class="benefits4">INFORMES 360º</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿podrías poner tu html para saber a qué corresponde cada clase? Lo del centro, el rombo amarillo, ¿Se escala también cuando cambia el tamaño de la pantalla o mantiene siempre el mismo tamaño?

Comment: la imagen cambia de tamaño pero cuando es movil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No uses margin para posicionar cosas, usa la cuailidad 'position' crea las clases css tal que asi:

```
.Beneficios {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
}
.benefitsN {
   position: absolute;
   top: 1%; //Distancia alejado de la parte de arriba del padre
   bottom: 1%; //Distancia alejado de la parte de abajo del padre
   left: 1%; //Distancia alejado de la parte de izquierda del padre
   right: 1%; //Distancia alejado de la parte de derecha del padre
}
```

La clase padre contenedor debera contener la cualidad siguiente

```
position: relative;
```

Comment: gracias. que bueno saber porque siempre usaba los margin-